# 1357133639816 milliseconds conversion in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, milliseconds, datetime-conversion

I have looked every where for a solution to convert **1357133639816 milliseconds** into **dd-mm-yyyy h:m:s** using **PHP 5.3** and also convert current server time into the same millisecond format as given above.

This value is an extract from an SMS on android with display time value of **02-Jan-2012 07:03 PM**

I have tried hard to find and test as many codes available online.

PS - http://codepad.org helped in quick execution of any test code (if you may like to test urs before posting).

Comment: I had seen that link and could not derive any solution for my query from it. Also, the value mentioned here for result validation. I did generic searches all along. But thanks.

Comment: @Vishal: Really, [the code given in that question didn't work for you?](http://codepad.org/3o8WSTzi) (ps. It's 2013 now.)

Answer (score 7):

Just like [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557959/php-convert-milliseconds-to-date) say, you simply need to convert the timestamp to seconds by dividing it by 1000 and then use [`date()`](http://php.net/date) to format it:

```php
$mil = 1357133639816;
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s T", $seconds);
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/YjRplm9B):

```
02-01-2013 13:33:59 UTC
```

To change the output to your local timezone, you can use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set):

```php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");

$mil = 1357133639816;
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s T", $seconds);
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/H51LX0JX):

```
02-01-2013 19:03:59 IST
```