# Convert wrong Android timestamp on Php date() function

Tags: php

I am getting  timestamp (1370956788472) of my android message  like this :

```
       cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"))
```

And trying to convert this android timestamp using php date() function and I am getting wrong Date and Time

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1370956788472');
   Output : 1997-04-28 09:50:48
```

But It will display correct  date and time  if i remove last three character from timestamp (removed 472 from 1370956788472) :

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1370956788');    
output: 2013-06-11 13:19:48
```

What is wrong here and what should i do can I divide my android timestamp with 1000

Comment: The difference is milliseconds vs seconds. So `/1000`

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: convert milliseconds to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557959/php-convert-milliseconds-to-date)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This time format `1370956788472` (the longer) is in milliseconds.

The shorter one `1370956788` is in seconds, we can get this type time by `$time = time()` in php.

so just divide 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to also adj by the host time aka webserver or localhost if your time is off.

For example my localhost server for developement is off by 25200 so it is

```
$myTime = time() - 25200;// to get the real time.

$phonetime = ($androidTime/1000) - 25200;
echo $phonetime;
```

Do if your time is off by hours or a day try adjusting and ever `hr = 3600`. So my 25200 is 7 hrs offset.