# PHP - milliseconds to hours:minutes (24 hour date)

Tags: php, time, format, clock, milliseconds

How can I get 24-hour format date (hours and minutes) from milliseconds?

I got this milliseconds value: `1433630097855`

I want it to print out the time in hours/minutes.
I can't remember exactly what time that was, but I think it's around 00:45

So it should print out like: 00:45

If it was 3 o'clock in afternoon, it should print out something like:
15:25

I couldn't find this conversion for 24h format and when it's 00:xx i tried some but it prints out just "0"

Like:

0:10

I want it like 00: in beginning.

Is there perhaps a quick command for this already in php or do i need some function?

Comment: PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) offers a whole range of date & time formatting options

Comment: You should see thoses threads : 

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557959/php-convert-milliseconds-to-date
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909871/getting-date-format-m-d-y-his-u-from-milliseconds

Comment: Assuming that it's milliseconds from 1-1-1970 00:00:00 GMT, `$var = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', intval(1433630097855 / 1000));
echo $var->format('H:i:s');` gives `22:34:57` today

Comment: Thats what Im trying to fix. Right now it's 01:19 CEST here. It gives me 13:19 for some reason when I use that code @MarkBaker

Comment: Well a Unix timestamp should be UTC, so you need to set the timezone for the DateTime object to your local time: `$var = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', intval(1433630097855 / 1000)); $var->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen')); echo $var->format('H:i:s');`

Answer (score 2):

Convert miliseconds to seconds `1433630097855 / 1000` and then just use seconds (integer timestamp) in datetime functions that you are familiar with. And don't forget about the [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

```php
$ms = 1433630097855;
$s = floor($ms/1000);
echo date('H:i:s', $s); # 22:34:57
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/376697)</kbd>

If you wish the output for other timezone, set it:

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date('H:i:s', $s); # 15:34:57
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/376698)</kbd>

You can even use [`DateTime` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), like:

```php
$dt = new DateTime("@$s");
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $dt->format('H:i:s'); # 15:34:57
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/376700)</kbd>

Comment: Nice solution, but it will only work for only max 24 hours :(

Comment: @DaVilchi: true, this is what OP needed. If you need to show also days, use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19680778/67332).

Comment: You saved my day, was looking for this answer for 4-6 hours :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use create a new date object form the timestamp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php