# What kind of timestamp is this I need to convert it to human readable

Tags: php, time

So i have a timestamp which i need to convert to human readable format however I cannot figure out which functions I need to use and which format this is.

`20180129T220300Z`

That is the timestamp and I need to convert that to human readable GMT +10 using PHP.

[image: Timestamp response]

Comment: [This one ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/557959/3282633)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen no, mine has letters in it as well. 20180129T220300Z please check my updated question which includes an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly know the name, but you can use it with the `DateTime` class.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('20180129T220300Z');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2018-01-29 22:03:00
?>
```

[More information about the class and its methods over here...](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)