# Convertint millisecond to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a table that contains time in milliseconds (2147483647), or so I have told. I am trying to convert it into the actual time (human time), but haven't been so lucky. I have tried everything I thought was going to be of help, though none of the things I have found on google, and on here, have been helpful.

```
SELECT arrivalTime, FROM_UNIXTIME(uploadTime), "; //UNIX_TIMESTAMP(uploadTime) * 1000 // UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000
```

The arrivalTime is uploaded in a different time format but I already have that working. I also have a different table using a different time format, which is also working but I am including it here on my post just in case it can be used as a reference or someone might find it useful in their code.

```
Date_Add('1970-01-01 0:0:0', INTERVAL(uploadTime/1000 - (timeZoneOffset*60)) SECOND) AS uploadTime
```

Any help or suggestion would be GREATLY appreciated!!!

PS: the current query gives me this  2038-01-18 22:14:07  as the time, which is obviously wrong. And I have also tried this

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(uploadTime/1000);
```

but didn't also do what I wanted

PSS: Okay, after asking around, I found out that this 2147483647 is from Android getTimeInMillis from calendar.API. Hope that helps anyone?

Comment: And what time is `2147483647` supposed to represent?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the actual date of when the report was uploaded

Comment: @azunyan That number also happens to be [PHP's max 32-bit integer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php). Seems odd is all

Comment: Your input looks suspiciously like 2^31-1, the largest 32-bit signed integer. I think you may have run into an overflow problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php: convert milliseconds to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557959/php-convert-milliseconds-to-date)

Comment: `2147483647` is `0x7FFFFFFF` which is unlikely to be correct, `2038-01-18 22:14:07` is a correct conversion of that value to time (in seconds)

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994889/converting-epoch-number-to-human-readable-date-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks of the inputs, guys! I will ask what the number represent or something. I do agree that the number is a bit strange. The time zone offset on this current table also contains the same number and all the data for the upload time have the same, as well. Which is weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this in SQL Server

```
DateAdd(Second, (2147483647/1000), CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime))  AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' AS uploadTime
```

This gives me the output:
[image]

After your update that the milliseconds comes from Android getTimeInMillis(): 
[image] 
Using this milliseconds in my function above:

```
DateAdd(Second, (1566302250040/1000), CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime))  AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'
```

results into `2019-08-20 11:57:30.000 +02:00` which seems to be right.

Comment: But the upload time cannot be in the 70's because the arrival time is this year. I was told that this 2147483647 is from Android getTimeInMillis from calendar.API. So far, I haven't found anything that converts it to the time that I need. But, thank you!

Comment: Ok thanks for more input. In that case, it seems that your milliseconds are wrong. I will update my answer with android screenshots shortly.

Comment: Is it possible that your upload time is not the exact time in Milliseconds but rather a difference (like `UploadTime = UPLOADEDTimeMilliSeconds - ArrivalTimeMilliSeconds` ) ? In that case you must use arrivalTime in place of '1970-01-01 00:00:00' in that DateAdd.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I do apologize for not being able to reply right away! I will ask around here in the office about that, but your screenshot seems the actual number that would be the ideal one! Even my boss said that the current number we have right now seemed weird, especially that each report has the same number for the upload time